# Print specific range of lines between two matches starting with a specific line after the first match

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

How can I print all data between two matches, staring from specific line after the first match. For example, let's say I have two patterns `Linux` and `Unix` and there are entries between these two words I would like to print data from specific line after the word `Linux`, in the example below line #6 after Linux, until the word `Unix`:

```
Linux
12
32
34
556
676
77
85434
rdb
232323
232435656
Unix
98736
4345
4546456
456
```

expected output:

```
85434
rdb
232323
232435656
```

How can I do it using awk, sed and grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
awk '/^Linux$/{flag=1;next}/^Unix$/{flag=0}flag' file | tail -n +7
```

Or without `tail`:

```
awk '/^Linux$/{flag=1;n=NR;next}/^Unix$/{flag=0};flag&&NR>(n+6);' file
```

Explanation:

- Search for pattern `^Linux$`, and if found, set `flag` to 1 (true) and move directly to `next` line.
- Go on until pattern `^Unix$` was found and set `flag` to 0 (false)
- The `flag` at the end is an awk specific notation. If `flag` is true, print the line, else do nothing.
- `flag` is just a variable name and can be anything, e.g. `f` or `printthisline`.

---

Using Gnu `sed`:

```
sed '/^Linux$/,/^Unix$/{//!b};d' file | tail -n +7
```

Comment: @downvoter: please leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you for help it worked for me this is what I want. could you explain awk command please?

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you see relative addressing, you should reach for `ed`.

```
echo '/Linux/+7,/Unix/-1p' | ed -s input_file.txt -
```

Or, as a heredoc:

```
ed -s input_file.txt - <<\EOF
/Linux/+7,/Unix/-1p
EOF
```

Comment: Wow, how easy, better than to struggel with `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

I would write one of

```
sed -n '/Linux/,/Unix/p' file | sed '1,7d;$d'
# or
awk '/Linux/ {nr = NR} /Unix/ {exit} nr && NR > nr+6' file
```

Comment: `sed -e '/Linux/,/Unix/!d;/Linux/{N;N;N;N;N;N;N;s/.*\n//' -e '}' -e '/Unix/d'` so as to avoid pipes and two `sed` invocations though really, `sed` should be avoided anytime one has to count stuff...

Comment: Yeah, I was fooling around with sed and loops, trying to cram it into a single sed program before I decided it wasn't worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

if you search with `grep` you can do this:

- `grep -A 5 "string used to search" <path-to-file(s)>` will show the 5 lines after the matched string
- `grep -B 5 "string used to search" <path-to-file(s)>` will show the 5 lines before the matched string
- `grep -C 5 "string used to search" <path-to-file(s)>` will show the 5 lines after and before the matched string (C stands for context)

for your example, it would be:
`grep -A 2 -B 1 "rdb" <path-to-file(s)>`

Comment: He wants to search key words Linux and Unix, not rdb. Although I think he doesn't know how many lines will lie in between.

Comment: given his statement: _How can I print all data between two matches, staring from specific line after the first match._ and his expected output, I wanted to make it simple. I guess your assumption _Although I think he doesn't know how many lines will lie in between._ was correct, but what I provided is not incorrect as per his request, is it?

Comment: yes it is incorrect, as OP says "*For example, let's say I have [...]*" which tells me that his text is just an example and not the real text. While your solution works for his example, it might not work for his real text.

Comment: Your answer is the moral equivalent of `sed -n '8,11p'` or `printf '85434\nrdb\n232323\n232435656\n'` — they all produce the requested output for the example input in a trivial way, but they don’t solve the problem as described.